# How to implement angular js in a already existing pure javaScript project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on a pure javaScript project in my company but now it has been decided that we will include angular js in our project for efficiency , maintenance and other stuffs. They do not fully want remove the javaScript coding like prototype inheritance and object creation . I mean do not want to change the entire project but add some features of angular js for some of it's benefits .

So my question is how can this be achieved just need a little direction to understand what all are the features of angular js can be used and how angular js can be used with already existing pure javaScript project ?

Comment: You should take a look at [VueJS](http://vuejs.org/), it's a lot easier and suitable for partial project development (if you really want to add a framework to your project). Also if you are looking for "efficiency", take a look at [Table Report](https://cdn.rawgit.com/krausest/js-framework-benchmark/956b068f03ef96a9c08d209ffadb0947cd56edc6/webdriver-java/table.html). AngularJS is more adapted to full project development.

Comment: If you want to add AngularJS for efficiency, please don't do it... :-( Vanilla JS if far more efficient... AngularJS usually augments project maintainability and extensibility. Also note that Angular 2 (the new version since a few weeks) has a *steep* learning curve...

Comment: @MarcoS Could you please explain how angular could be used for project maintainability and extensibility ?

Comment: This is not a matter for a comment, sorry... :-( However, adopting an MVC pattern, can ease project maintanibility, and AngularJS fits very well in MVC (see for example http://letzgro.net/blog/why-we-suggest-angularjs-for-building-maintainable-web-applications/). More, AngularJS architecture is based on modules (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html), which easily allow extending a project...

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using Angular 1.x it is actually pretty easy to integrate it into your existing project. You can use angular on the components you wish to use and leave the remaining code to your pure js approach. 
The angular tutorial is the best place to start:
[AngularJS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/)

Comment: Ok.. but for which features we should use angular 1.x like ajax calls , listing and SPA ? I am just trying to understand  I have some knowledge on angular js so learning is not a problem I am just trying to understand how can i implement it in my current project